# Laravel Sanctum 401 error after on reloading

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum, unauthorized

I am using Laravel Sanctum's API Tokens to authenticate requests from a React application. I don't use SPA Authentication and cookies.

For now, the Laravel sessions are managed with files.

After you login, you get a token, and with the given token, you can call APIs successfully. But if you refresh a page, even with the same token, API calls fail with 401 status code and the following message:

```
{
  "message": "Given authorization token is not valid. Please try to login again."
}
```

It works fine on my `localhost`. It only happens on a live site, and after you refresh a page.

The Laravel backend serves only APIs, so it defines routes in `api.php` only. All these routes are using `auth:sanctum` middleware (of course, with an exception of `/login` route).

The following line is disabled in `Kernel.php` for the `api` middleware group:

```
\Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Middleware\EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class
```

Any thoughts on how to fix this?

Comment: What request headers do you sent with your reload?

Comment: The same request headers as the initial request that's sent right after the login.